# Do the universities or laboratories or organizations provide housing facility during post-doctoral?

Tags: postdocs, france

I am interested in Post-doctoral degree in mathematics in France or in general in Europe  after my PhD.

Do the universities or laboratories or organizations provide housing facility ?

Can you suggest me how is it possible ?

Comment: Pretty institution specific. But, when I did a post-doc in Europe (from US), the institute both (1) had some apartments on hand for visitors and (2) would help finding housing if those were not suitable. It is not unusual, particularly for those moving to a new country, to need help navigating the housing market.

Comment: Yes , no, maybe... you have to ask the institution.

Comment: As I understand it, in France, very few students, even undergraduates, live in university housing.  A significant percentage live with their parents; most of the remainder rent apartments by themselves or with friends just like non-students.  However, most universities will offer help in finding housing to international students and postdocs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a post-doc, you generally would have to look at the particular institution(s) you are considering.  Generally, the bulk of on-campus housing goes towards undergraduates, with some reserved for graduate students.  But by that time, although there will be some graduate students living on campus if they can, a good amount look to live off-campus (primarily due to it being a lesser cost than on campus).

Post-docs will have even lesser priority, if any at all, for living on campus, so generally you would have to look to get housing on your own.  This experience goes for the USA, by the way, but the off-campus living situation, based on the other answer, seems to be very in line with the way housing is done in Europe (for graduate students and post-docs).  Again, it varies on your institution, so I would say get in contact with people there if you need assistance with housing.

Answer (score 3):

This depends what you mean by “provide” but it is extremely unlikely an institution would provide accommodation *free of charge* for a postdoc (it’s unlikely they would provide such free housing for students unless there were special circumstances of some sort).  The institution might have residences but you should expect to have to pay for that.

A postdoc is like a job, and I doubt you expect employers to “provide” housing.  Universities - like employers - might have access to rental listings and *might* help your find housing but otherwise you’re on your own.

Usually if housing *is* provided, it would be made explicit in the job offer.

Comment: I suspect quite a lot of institutions have an office (housing assistance) that helps new employees find suitable housing. Probably open to post docs also. Just a "finding" service, though. They even do this for students in the US. A sort of registration place for private renters.

Comment: @Buffy I would suspect the same (especially in the bigger institutions).